# I have a question on SIFT

Tags: sift

I am reading a paper on SIFT by Lowe.

In it, gradient magnitudes and orientations are calculated using these formulae:

[image]
$$$$
I don't know why m(x,y) is calculated above. I heard that gradient magnitude is usually calculated like the following.

$$\sqrt{f_x ^2 + f_y^2}
$$

Comment: what is f_x and f_y in your case? they are gradients, right? try to compare it with terms in SIFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizontal and vertical gradients are computed by taking neighbor pixel differences:

$$g_{x}=L(x+1,y)-L(x-1,y)\\g_{y}=L(x,y+1)-L(x,y-1)$$

Gradient magnitude is computed the same way as in your formula:

$$m(x,y)=\sqrt{g_x^2+g_y^{2}}$$

Replacing $g_{x}$ and $g_{y}$ with above will give you the original formula.

Gradients are usually computed by forward or [central difference formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward.2C_backward.2C_and_central_differences), but I think in this case the above is still accurate enough since the image $L$ is smoothed.

Comment: I still have a little doubt, but thank you very much :)

Comment: Okay. You can consult the [Image gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient#Math) wiki article. There is some brief explanation and similar formulas (same meaning).